# GetPostBackClientHyperlink stops when navigating a second grid on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two grids on my page. On pageload both grids have data as expected

The first grid has this event on rowdatabound

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
    }
}
```

The first grid's row click works as expected. When I start navigating through the second grid using the 'next' button, the rowclick on the first grid stops working. The next button click on the second grid is as below

```
    protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int pageindex = (int)ViewState["Current"] + 1;
            if (pageindex < grdImages.PageCount)
            {
                grdImages.PageIndex = pageindex;
                BindSecondGrid();
                ViewState["Current"] = pageindex;
            }
            else
            {
                BindSecondGrid();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch exception
        }
    }
```

The datasource on the second grid is completely different to first grid and the the DataBind() on the first is never called during navigation of the second grid. Any idea what could be wrong?

Any idea why it would happen?

Comment: You should have to rebind the Click and Tool-tip on next.

Comment: But I am navigating on the second grid not the first?